# while implementing actionlister in java eclipe ide

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

My Code is:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("ok"); //JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Ok");

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 

{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getSource().equals(btnNewButton))
        {

        }
}
```

when i wrote this still getting error. if(arg0.getSource().equals(btnNewButton)) getting error please any one fix it

Comment: what kind of error ? post the error you have got!

Answer (score 6):

Anonymous internal classes can't access local variables, unless they have been declared **final**. Changing the declaration of `btnNewButton` to `final JButton btnNewButton = ..."` would make it work.

However, since you are using an anonymous listener that is attached to nothing else but `btnNewButton`, you already know the event source must be `btnNewButton`, and the whole check is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("ok"); //JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Ok");

btnNewButton.addActionListener(this); 


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if(ae.getSource().equals(btnNewButton))
        {
     ////do your code here 
        }
```